# this code works but when the page is reloaded previous item gets added

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
<form method="post" action="cart.php?action=add&code=<?php echo $product_array[$key]["code"]; ?>"
    <div class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $product_array[$key]["image"]; ?>"></div>
    <div><strong><?php echo $product_array[$key]["name"]; ?></strong></div>
    <div class="product-price"><?php echo "₹ ".$product_array[$key]["price"]; ?></div>
    <div><input type="Number" name="quantity" value="1" size="2" min="0.5" max="10" step="0.5" style="border-radius: 50px;width: 70px;height: 40px; border-style: ridge;text-align: center;" /><input type="submit" value="Add to cart" class="btn btn-warning"  /></div>&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <b>Note: Quantity should be in KG's</b>
</form>
</div> adding previous item when page reloads
```

Comment: How do you reset the code in `code=<?php echo $product_array[$key]["code"]; ?>` on reload

Comment: the item will added to the cart but when i reload the page the previous item gets added again into the cart....i dont know how to reset the code or send it only once

Comment: You can check whether the product is already there in the cart before adding it to the cart. You can not send only once anyway. Instead you can redirect once the product added to cart.

Comment: case "add":
    if(!empty($_POST["quantity"])) {
      $productByCode = $db_handle->runQuery("SELECT * FROM tblproduct WHERE code='" . $_GET["code"] . "'");
      $itemArray = array($productByCode[0]["code"]=>array('name'=>$productByCode[0]["name"], 'code'=>$productByCode[0]["code"], 'quantity'=>$_POST["quantity"], 'price'=>$productByCode[0]["price"])); this is how it gets added

Comment: modify <form> tag to <form method="post" action="cart.php?action=add&code=<?php echo $product_array[$key]['code']; ?>">

Comment: no that did not work

Comment: for now i'm redirecting to cart.php...that works for me